# Using std::map on COM objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management, com, stl

I'm attempting to create a map of COM objects to a specific hash, like that of a string. This is for a caching algorithm I'm implementing. The idea is if you attempt to load a file that has been already opened by a previous line of code, it will return the already created block of memory as an IStream and not bother reloading the file into memory. The one problem I have run into is with COM objects auto destroying themselves when their last reference is deleted. The original container doesn't know the object has been destroyed, and, when you go to access an object that has been freed, it returns the invalid memory handle instead of loading the file. Is there a better way to implement this, or should I give up on STL and instead make my own container?

Comment: Use a smart pointer to the COM object in your map. This way it will hold a reference until it is no longer needed preventing it from being prematurely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, the code that put the interface pointer in the container forgot to call AddRef().  *Never* store pointers to COM interfaces without increasing their reference count.

Comment: The container didn't *forget* to call AddRef, it was never designed to do so in the first place. Call AddRef yourself before adding it to the container, or use a smart pointer - Microsoft helpfully provides 2 to choose from.

Comment: I ended up writing my own algorithm for containers that can contain COM objects. It seemed simpler than rewriting the majority of the codebase.